# Adding and removing objects from a list in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, mobile, collections

I have List of type dynamic called selectedList, it should hold a list of objects.
each objects consists of teacherId and subjectId,
Like this   [ {1,2},{4,9},{7,3} ... etc]

what I want to achieve is that I can remove and add objects to this list, if the object is exist it should be removed and if it's not it should be added.

I tried contain method but it didn't work !

**The Adding method**

```
List<dynamic> selectedList = [];

void addTeacher(Teachers teacherId, Subjectt subjectId) {
if (this.selectedList.contains({  *** this method is not working***     })) {
  this.selectedList.remove({teacherId, subjectId});
  this.myColor = Colors.grey;
  print('removed teacher => ${teacherId.toString()}');
} else {
  this.selectedList.add({teacherId, subjectId});
  this.myColor = AsasColors().blue;
  print('added teacher => ${teacherId.toString()}');
}
notifyListeners();
print(selectedList);}
```

**where I'm calling the method**

```
                                      ListTile(
```

> onTap: () {
> card.addTeacher(
> e,
> cardData.subjects[
> subjectIndex]);
> },

```
                                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                                backgroundColor:
                                                    AsasColors().white,
                                                backgroundImage:
                                                    NetworkImage(
                                                        e.profilePicture),
                                              ),
                                              title: MediumRegularFont(
                                                string: e.name,
                                              ),),
```

Please Help I'm really tired of this problem!

Comment: You are calling setState() after adding or removing object?

Comment: no, I'm writing this method in changeNotifier class with  notifyListeners() at the end of this method and i wrapped my list tile with Consumer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned `Object` and since `contains` method is not working

```dart
...
if (this.selectedList.contains({  *** this method is not working***     })) ...
```

#### Step 1

I suppose you are using contains for objects without overriding their hashcode and equallity operator

eg:

```dart
class Teacher {
  String id;
  String name;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
  
    return other is Teacher &&
      other.id == id;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

#### Step 2

Since you are using `Set` in the list, you have to comapre them in a different way

Also remove `this` keyword, it's not nessecerly

```dart
List<Set> selectedList = [];

void addTeacher(Teachers teacherId, Subjectt subjectId) {
if (selectedList.indexWhere((element) => 
   element.first == teacherId && element.last == subjectId)) != -1 ) {
  selectedList.remove({teacherId, subjectId});
  myColor = Colors.grey;
  print('removed teacher => ${teacherId.toString()}');
} else {
  selectedList.add({teacherId, subjectId});
  myColor = AsasColors().blue;
  print('added teacher => ${teacherId.toString()}');
}
notifyListeners();
print(selectedList);
}
```

`List().indexWhere` method will return `-1` if the element was not found in the list. you can use other methods like `List().every` too

(Instead of `Set`, I recommend you to use `Map` for code readabiliy and reduce complexity)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I did this before but actually I'm kind new  to this filed and i don't know what to type in contains method, should I check like this now  ?   if (this.selectedList.contains( {teacherId . id,subjectId}) )  ??

Comment: @FarisShomali i've updated my answer, I didn't know you were using sets at first time